# My input type="submit" is not displaying?

Tags: jquery, forms

why is my `<input type="submit"` not display on http://ballpointradio.com/new/page_edit.php? It's supposed to be underneath the textarea.

This really is baffling me!! Is it my jQuery? I'm pretty sure it isn't...

Comment: It *is* something with your jQuery. When I have JavaScript disabled (which I did initially), it displays at the right of the second text area. When it is enabled, neither the text area or the submit button show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#page_selection").change(function(){
    $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});
$("page_selection").change();
```

This code, on load, does this:

```
$("#edit1").show().siblings().hide();
```

Considering that the `<input type="submit">` is a sibling of `$('edit1')`, it gets hidden!

Just change `.siblings()` to `.siblings('textarea')` so it only hides siblings that are also textareas!

Answer (score 4):

It has `style="display: none"` set.

I wasn't able to immediately figure out why, though.

I'm not a jquery man, but you could look if some of the `hide()` method calls could be interfering. This one, for example:

```
$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
```

Comment: To confirm Lauri's answer, it's definitely Javascript hiding the submit button. When you disable Javascript the button appears normally. I'd be taking a hard look at the line above too.